# D3.js how to get the position/offset of x and y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

For a given plot with a X and Y axis, how would one get the position of the X and Y axis? I guess I would need the offsets of the two axes. Please advise.

Comment: Some code would help us give an answer. But you just give them an id and select them to get their positions ? What positions are you after ?

Comment: Please have a look at this plot I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/we118d8e/

Comment: what is it youre trying to find the position of ? Just the x position of the y axis and the y position of the x ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy The average lines are drawn on the plot without taking into account the offsets of the x and y axes. I want the lines to be drawn along 0.5, 0.5 of the plot

Comment: @thatOneGuy I am not able to follow what you mean by "just give them an id and select them to get their positions". To answer your question, yes, I need the x position of the y axis and the y position of the x axis. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I didnt understand your question. What you want is to plot the lines on the axis rather than get the positions of the x and y axis'. Youre using nvd3 which i know nothing about. Im not 100% how the scales work with nvd3 im afraid :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest your elements in the container element that has the boundaries you want.

For example, if you want that your x axis start in the boundary of the y axis, replace (in line 66)

```
  svg.append("line")
```

With

```
 d3.select(".nv-scatterWrap").append("line")
```